# Equivalent of “married” for people in a relationship?

Tags: word-choice, kinship-terms

When asked the question “Are you in a relationship?” an appropriate answer would be “No, I’m married.” However, if asked “Are you married?” you may say "No, I’m in a relationship.”

But my question is, what is the equivalent of the word *married* for people who are in a relationship?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Didn't spot that mistake.

Comment: In what country is a marriage not considered a relationship?

Answer (score 8):

"Relationship" is a term with multiple meanings.

Marriage itself is a relationship. So when you are asked "Are you in a relationship?", an appropriate answer would be "**Yes**, I'm married".

There are other relationships, such as brother and sister, parent and child, colleagues, friends, tenant and landlord, and so on. However "are you in a relationship" usually refers to a monogamous relationship with a boyfriend/girlfriend -- you wouldn't answer the question "Yes, I have a sister".

There is no commonly-used word that you can just plug into a sentence that means "in a monogamous loving relationship but not married".

If the couple are living together, you might say they are *cohabiting*, more informally *shacked up*, or simply *living together*.

Words such as *courting*, *going steady*, *seeing someone* would be widely understood, but may seem outdated or incongruous to some people. ("Courting" is the language of my grandparents' generation; "Going steady" is the language of a 1980s American high school sitcom, etc.)

Comment: Other words that come into play here: "dating" usually means a relationship in its earlier stages, and "in a committed relationship" usually means a status similar to marriage.  (A marriage is also a committed relationship, but you'd usually say "married" unless this is, say, some government/insurance/employment/etc form where the relevant factor is just "is there someone else being covered or not?".)

Comment: Careful with "dating". It can mean "in the early stages of a relationship", but it can also mean "going on dates with a string of new potential partners on a regular basis"

Comment: Yes, dating is either un- or not-yet committed, and in the "un-" case could involve multiple partners, sequentially or concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while but I used the expression "spoken for" as in "I'm sorry but you'll just have to make do with the *second* most wonderful man in the world. I'm spoken for."

Comment: Yes, it is a little dated (not to mention self-deprecatory), but if I needed to say it I'd probably rather this than "attached" (which to me suggests you see yourself as a barnacle or some other kind of parasite).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "attached".  In most contexts this would be understood and it is not particularly colloquial like the other answers offered.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not see the distinction between "in a relationship" and "married", unless you are offered up both (such as when you are selecting your "status" in Facebook).

Saying that you are in a relationship will include marriage, but also people who are not.

In England, a colloquial version might be to say:

> Q: "Are you married?"
>
> A: "No, but I'm seeing someone."

(Other usages might be "courting" or "going steady").

Comment: I see a pretty obvious distinction between "in a relationship" and "married" - the time scale. The phrase "in a relationship" moves the needle from just to the right of "one-night stand" all the way to "until death do us part". The word "married" states an expectation well over on the right side of the gauge - even if it doesn't necessarily work out that way.